# How to enable ClangCodeModel on Qt Creator

Tags: qt

So, how does one enable it?

Fedora 25 64bit

LLVM 3.9.1 packages installed: llvm; llvm-devel; llvm-libs

clang 3.9.1 packages installed: clang; clang-analyser; clang-devel; clang-libs

Qt 5.8.0         - built from source
Qt Creator 4.2.2 - built from source
Plugins:
loaded:
Code Analyser:
ClangStaticAnalyzer
NOT loaded:
  ClangCodeModel

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html
says:
"If you build Qt Creator yourself, add ${LLVM_INSTALL_DIR}\bin to the PATH variable so the LLVM libraries will be found on startup."

https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/README.md
says:
"You can build Qt Creator with
    # Optional, needed for the Clang Code Model:
    export LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/path/to/llvm "

So what's the value for LLVM_INSTALL_DIR on this Fedora 25 setup to get the ClangCodeModel enabled? /usr/bin?

Comment: Have you enabled it in the Help->About Plugins section?

Comment: @ Leherenn: The ClangCodeModel option is not in the Help->About Plugins->C++ to enable or disable.

Comment: I do not have Linux at hand right now and also don't remember the path I use, but have a look at https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/tree/src/shared/clang/clang_installation.pri. There you can see, what files are looked up. For you the interesting part is `$$LLVM_INSTALL_DIR/bin/llvm-config`. So search for llvm-config and substitute LLVM_INSTALL_DIR accordingly. Hope that helps finding the right path. Good luck!

Comment: @Lorenz: Tried LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/usr and /usr/bin at my first builds of Qt Creator.
The Windows builds caused no problem as. It seems the build system is looking for an all-in-one install path of the LLVM & Clang - LLVM_INSTALL_DIR -, and not distributed as done in the separate packages of llvm and clang on the Fedora 25 distro.
I will look in to the pri file you mention - when I get the time.

Comment: I've checked the clang_installation.pri file -it's working OK with LLVM_INSTALL_DIR=/usr. So why isn't the ClangCodeModel shared libraries not built?

Comment: What a dunce! I used an old script of mine and it worked, did the job. When on the command line I was forgetting to export that LLVM_INSTALL_DIR.
I'll have to stop doing Windows DOS batch scripting!